# Need help searching my sql

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I need help with a script that searches 8 different fields in same table, but want it to also give result if one or three parameters are not searced for. I am using PHP and MySql and I have been trying my way with this for a very long time and now I turn to you experts here.
I am using both select boxes and tic boxes. Can you please help me with this.

```
Select * FROM mymembers WHERE 
country = $country AND
gender = $gender AND
haircolor = $haircolor AND
hairlength = $hairlength AND
```

The problem comes when one of theese dont have result.....?????
Please Help
Carsten

Comment: Manually check which **select** or **checkbox** are all selected, then use variable to append conditions with your `WHERE` clause

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it lacks a basic level of research.

Answer (score 0):

Build your SQL using PHP. Check if the variables are not empty and then add them.

E.g.

```
$sql = 'Select * FROM mymembers WHERE ';
if (!empty($country)) $sql .= 'country = '.$country;
```

Make sure to escape any variables you use in your SQL to prevent injections.

Comment: Is it possible to use this approach when using arrays also?

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned: *want it to also give result if one or three parameters are not searced for*

In this case, you need to use the `OR` conditional operator.

Code:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM mymembers WHERE 
country = '" . $country . "' OR
gender = '" . $gender . "' OR
haircolor = '" . $haircolor . "' OR
hairlength = '" . $hairlength . "'";
```

In my opinion, the best way to query this table is to use "checkboxes", "radio buttons" and "select dropdown" to refine the search, because "most-likely" the values of `country`, `gender`, `haircolor` and `hairlength` are predefined and they won't probably change.
If it's a "search box", then you can rely on the `LIKE` operator, but in your case, the results will be awful.